# HBox vs ToolBar: Different horizontal alignment

Tags: javafx

How can I algin the `CheckBox` in the `HBox` example as it is done by the `ToolBar`?

Example HBox:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Example ToolBar:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>

<ToolBar xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
   <items>
      <TextField />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
   </items>
</ToolBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `alignment="CENTER"` and `spacing="4.0"` to HBox tag

and

```
<padding>
   <Insets bottom="4.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" top="4.0" />
</padding>
```

inner HBox tag, that should be all.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the alignment to BASELINE_LEFT.

```
<HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" ...
```

...and add spacing and insets as per the other answer.
You want BASELINE instead of CENTER to keep the text aligned properly.